# Manually release Google Play

Tags: android, version, store, release, playback

I want to upload a new release for my existing app on Google Play, but I don't want it to publish yet.

Is there a way to manually publish a new version to store after it is approved by Google team (like App Store) ?

Answer (score 1):

Go to Publishing overview > manage and activate the active managed publication